# Using class and ngClass on the same element

Tags: html, css, angular

I have something like this:

```
<div class="alert-container {{ type }}" [ngClass]="{ label: hasLabel }">
```

The `label` class should be added if `hasLabe`l is `true`, which is accomplished with `ngClass`.

But I also have `type` variable and the value of it is used as the name of class that should be applied to element.

But this is what happens. Chaning `hasLabel` to `true` adds label class correctly, but then when `type` is changed, label class is removed, because `class="alert-container {{ type }}"` overrides it. So any other class that is applied to element will be removed when `type` changes.

I tried this as solution:

```
<div class="alert-container {{ type }} {{ hasLabel  ? 'label' : '' }}">
```

But I like ngClass more for conditional classes. So my question is, is this the only solution or is there any other solution so I can continue using both class and ngClass as in first example?

Comment: <div class="alert-container" [ngClass]="{ 'label': hasLabel, 'type': type }"> It may be work

Comment: Could you please add a StackBlitz that demonstrates your error? I seem to be getting both classes applied as expected in the scenario you describe: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yaa65r

Comment: Put everything in [ngClass] and provide the object in a variable in TypeScript.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment I see it works correctly on stackblitz but I copied your code to my app and it still behaves as I described. Maybe its down to angualar version? I am using angular 11.